# create a post request using poltergeist and capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, phantomjs, poltergeist

I'm transitioning from Capybara backed by the default Rack driver to Capybara backed by Poltergeist.

For frustrating reasons, I need to manipulate session data before loading a page. But I couldn't figure out how to manipulate the session directly with the Rack driver, so I

```
Capybara.current_session.driver.submit :post, "/current_search", {:session => :data }
```

Unfortunately, the Poltergeist `driver` object has no `submit` method, as the Rack driver had.

There are three possibilities:

- **How do I submit a POST request with poltergeist/phantomjs?** (Implementing this seems the easiest)
- How can I manipulate session data directly with poltergeist/phantomjs?
- I can restructure the code so that manipulating session data directly is no longer necessary. This would be time-consuming and is low-priority.

PS: due to being on Ruby 1.8, we are stuck on [Poltergeist v1.0.2](https://github.com/jonleighton/poltergeist/tree/v1.0.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of capybara is to test user interaction, so you can do the POST request in the same way a user would do.

On your case it would be something like:

```
visit '/search'
fill_in '.search-box', :with => "search query"
click_on "Submit"
```

Is there any reason to not do it this way?

Comment: The page with the form is very javascript-heavy, and what I'm actually testing doesn't even require javascript. So it just seems like an enormous amount of unrelated setup for every single test, which will easily take up more than half the time of the test run.

Comment: For now the specs are commented out. Sometime soon we're making the views in question accept GET params; then these tests will be re-added. Because you're completely right, and we just wrote this in an untestable way.

Comment: @chadoh, I understand your problem now. Yeah, the best solution would be to refactor that, but maybe you can try the solution [here](http://railsware.com/blog/2012/01/07/accessing-application-session-in-capybara/) for now. Remember to add a story somewhere to refactor this as soon as you have time.